# Huxtable: color code a matrix by another matrix

Tags: r

Is it possible to color-code a table (generated with huxtable) through the colors given in a *different table*?

```
head_mtcars <- head(mtcars)
tbl_A <- as_hux(head_mtcars[1:2])
tbl_B <- as_hux(head_mtcars[3:4])
```

1) As a start, I would like to colorize the elements in column 1 and 2 of `tbl_A` by a colorspace for each column respectively

```
tbl_A %>% 
  huxtable::add_colnames() %>% 
  map_background_color("for each column of tbl_A", by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green"))
```

2) Next, I would like to colorize the elements in column 1 and 2 of `tbl_A` by a colorspace for each column of tbl_B,
   i.e., the elements in col 1 of table `tbl_A` by `tbl_B[,1]` and the elements in col 2 of table `tbl_A` by `tbl_B[,2]`

```
tbl_A %>% 
huxtable::add_colnames() %>% 
  map_background_color("for each column of tbl_B", by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green"))
```

3) Finally, not by column but for a whole table: colorize elements in ht by the values of ht2:

```
ht <- as_hux(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
ht2 <- as_hux(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
map_background_color(ht, by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green"))
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you committed to huxtable, or could you consider other table methods? Here is one solution with flextable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677080/r-flextable-conditional-formatting-based-on-pairs-of-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part A: to apply colourspaces by column, you have to specify them separately:

```
tbl_A %>% 
  map_background_color(everywhere, 1, by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green")) %>%
  map_background_color(everywhere, 2, by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green")) %>%
  huxtable::add_colnames()
```

This might be a feature request because I can imagine doing it by column is a common use case.

Part B: I think doing this "manually" is going to be simplest - i.e. construct the colours you want and then use them in `set_background_color`. We can use huxtable's `by_colorspace` outside of a `map_` call, like this. Again, done separately by columns:

```
# this is hairy. Details in ?"huxtable::mapping-functions"
colors1 <- by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green")(tbl_B, 1:6, 1, 
      matrix(NA, 6, 1))
colors2 <- by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green")(tbl_B, 1:6, 2, 
      matrix(NA, 6, 1))

tbl_A %>% 
  set_background_color(everywhere, 1:2, cbind(colors1, colors2)) %>% 
  huxtable::add_colnames()
```

Part C, so, the colour mapping is not done within individual columns, but over the whole table:

```
colors_all <- by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green")(tbl_B, 1:6, 1:2, 
  matrix(NA, 6, 2))

tbl_A %>% 
  set_background_color(everywhere, 1:2, colors_all) %>% 
  huxtable::add_colnames()
```

*Update*. In github master, which will probably become huxtable 4.8.0, you can indeed now do:

```
tbl_A %>% 
  map_background_color(everywhere, 1:2, 
    by_colorspace("orange", "white", "green", colwise = TRUE))
```

rather than calling `map_...` for each column separately.

Comment: Thank you so much @dash2 for your great and very helpful solutions! Many thanks also for considering to include the `colwise = TRUE` option in huxtable 4.8.0.

Comment: Pleasure. It's out now (actually in 4.7.1).